# IdenitityServer WsFederation Claims

Tags: ws-federation, claims, eid, identityserver3

I'm setting up IdentityServerv3 with an external IdentityProvider using the WsFederation protocol.

For adding the provider I've following code, but I don't understand how I can read the claim's, like name, firstname, photo given back by this provider.

```
var eContract = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "EId",
    Caption = "E-Id",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
    MetadataAddress =
        "https://www.e-contract.be/eid-idp/endpoints/ws-federation/metadata/auth-ident-metadata.xml",
    Wtrealm = "https://localhost:44333/core",
};
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(eContract);
```

I know that for example the photo should be ***be:fedict:eid:idp:photo***

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an IUserService to deal with external providers.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/userService.html